# Mounting large mirror on drywall/studs with unknown brackets

Tags: mirror, mount

We got a large beveled mirror (50-60 lbs) at a garage sale thinking it would be easy to mount. After we got home we noticed the mirror has 2 brackets near one of the longer edges and I am baffled on how to mount with those. Can anyone help me?

[image: mirror bracket]

Comment: Leaving this as a comment  as it is speculation on my part. This type of bracketry is typically used for a attaching a mirror to a set off drawers either a bureau or chest of drawers

Comment: There was a horizontal metal bar that went under the metal straps. A pair of vertical metal bars attached to these horizontal ones and attached to the back of a dresser or chest.

Comment: There’s more than one way to skin a cat and just because those brackets are on the mirror now doesn’t mean you have to use them, you can take them off and come up with a better solution such as a French cleat or D rings and picture wire.

Answer (score 1):

If there are brackets (straps) on both sides about 1/3 of the way down from the top, then you could use S-hooks in the straps (remove the center clamping screw) and string a heavy steel wire between them. Then hook the wire on a heavy nail into a stud or use one of the new stronger hangers like a WingIt into drywall.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The brackets in the picture are way at the top (around 1/10th of the way down). The mirror is actually on it's shorter edge in the picture, the other bracket is on the same edge below the one shown. Can I install new straps on to the back? Do you think it would withstand the mirror's weight?

Comment: My grandmother had a makeup desk that a very large mirror sat on the straps were just like your photo shows the weight of the mirror rested on the desk the straps were just there to keep it from flipping over, I believe both Mike's and Jim are saying the same thing as this. I would not try to suspend the mirror from those brackets I would purchase mirror clips to screw into the studs on the wall or make a frame. You don't want to be picking up glass shards.